# Find Kubernetes namespace creator

Tags: kubernetes

How do you find the creator of a namespace in Kubernetes? There was a debate today about who had created a namespace and we weren't able to find who the creator was.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't configure it already you cannot, the information is not being saved by Kubernetes unless you explicitly want to log it.

In order to do so you would have to activate [audit logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/).
Audit logs can be customized to a high degree and can contain information such as *when* did *who* do *what*. This also includes the creation of namespaces.